# How do I return realm object or create one if empty?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Suppose I have a SearchText object as such:

```
class SearchText: Object {
    dynamic var text: String = ""
}
```

I would like to create an accessor such that I can get that object if it exists or create one if it doesn't. This is what I have.

```
extension Realm {
    var searchText: SearchText {
        if let searchText = objects(SearchText.self).first {
            return searchText
        } else {
            let searchText = SearchText()
            try! write {
                add(searchText)
            }
            return searchText
        }
}
```

This kinda works but here is my problem. I would like to use searchText and also update its value. Something like:

```
func updateSearchText(text: String) {
        try! write {
            searchText?.text = text
        }
    }
```

When I try to `updateSearchText`, I get a realm exception of `Realm is already in a write transaction`. I think it's because I'm nesting to writes: creating the text and then updating it.

How would I do this elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

Realm doesn't provide nested transaction currently. There is a way to avoid the exception is check you're in write transaction before open a transaction. Like the following:

```
func updateSearchText(text: String) {
    func update() {
        searchText?.text = text
    }

    if inWriteTransaction {
        update()
    } else {
        try! write {
            update()
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe searchText setter also should be:

```
var searchText: SearchText {
    if let searchText = objects(SearchText.self).first {
        return searchText
    } else {
        let searchText = SearchText()
        if inWriteTransaction {
            add(searchText)
        } else {
            try! write {
                add(searchText)
            }
        }
        return searchText
    }
}
```